# How to find the 5 letters with the most number of occurrences in a string?

Tags: python, string, project

How can I find the 5 letters with the most occurrences in this string, with ties decided in alphabetical order?

Example:
'aaaaa-bbb-zx-yz-xy'

Comment: Take a look at `collections.Counter()`.

Comment: Please add input, and expected output, and also what  you have done

Comment: Are you looking to count *only* letters? Do you count `-` or other non-letter characters?

Comment: Barmar's comment plus using `sorted` should get you there

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp I'm looking to count only letters.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> s = 'aaaaa-bbb-zx-yz-xy'
>>> {char: count for char, count in sorted(\
    collections.Counter(\
            re.sub(r'\W+','',s))\
        .most_common(5),\
    key = lambda item: (-item[1], item[0]))}
{'a': 5, 'b': 3, 'x': 2, 'y': 2, 'z': 2}
```

Comment: since those are parentheses you don't need to use  \ if you continue with a closed parenthesis on a new line or continue something that will have a closed parenthesis